# Working with tortoisehg to manage git repository

Tags: git, tortoisehg

I used to work with tortoise hg on mercurial, and I really really love tortoise hg.
Now I'm working on a project which is based on Git.
I really need tortoise hg because of its workbench. It's not existed in the tortoise git.
Would it be possible to work with tortoise hg in a git repository?

I have tried many other clients in windows, such as git extensions, source tree and more. really missing tortoise hg in the git project....
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best alternative: [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/)

> This is the Hg-Git plugin for Mercurial, adding the ability to push to
>   and pull from a Git server repository from Mercurial. This means you
>   can collaborate on Git based projects from Mercurial, or use a Git
>   server as a collaboration point for a team with developers using both
>   Git and Mercurial.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't [Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org) an option?

It has some [features](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-intro-features.html) in common with Tortoise Hg.